# Expected an indented block in Python game

Tags: python

I'm writing a program to play Connect Four with Python and I'm not sure how to resolve the "expected an indented block" error that is being thrown at me in certain areas. Any time I try running a [row][col] section, it throws the error up. I'm using some example code to help me develop my own and here's what I'm using:

```
import random

def winner(board):
"""This function accepts the Connect 4 board as a parameter.  
If there is no winner, the function will return the empty string "".  
If the user has won, it will return 'X', and if the computer has
won it will return 'O'."""

# Check rows for winner
for row in range(6):
for col in range(3):
    if (board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] == board[row][col + 2] ==\
        board[row][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
    return board[row][col]

# Check columns for winner
for col in range(6):
for row in range(3):
    if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col] == board[row + 2][col] ==\
        board[row + 3][col]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
        return board[row][col]

# Check diagonal (top-left to bottom-right) for winner

for row in range(3):
for col in range(4):
    if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col + 1] == board[row + 2][col + 2] ==\
        board[row + 3][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
        return board[row][col]


# Check diagonal (bottom-left to top-right) for winner

for row in range(5, 2, -1):
for col in range(3):
    if (board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col + 1] == board[row - 2][col + 2] ==\
        board[row - 3][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
        return board[row][col]

# No winner: return the empty string
return ""

def display_board(board):

print "   1   2   3   4    5   6   7"
print "1: " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] + " | " + board[0][3] + " |    " + board[0][4] + " | " + board[0][5] + " | " + board[0][6] + " | " + board[0][7]
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---"
print "2: " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] + " | " + board[1][3] + " | " + board[1][4] + " | " + board[1][5] + " | " + board [1][6] + " | " + board [1][7]  
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
print "3: " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] + " | " + board[2][3] + " | " + board [2][4] + " | " + board [2][5] + " | " + board [2][6] + " | " + board [2][7]
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
print "4: " + board[3][0] + " | " + board[3][1] + " | " + board[3][2] + " | " + board[3][3] + " | " + board [3][4] + " | " + board [3][5] + " | " + board [3][6] + " | " + board [3][7]
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
print "5: " + board[4][0] + " | " + board[4][1] + " | " + board[4][2] + " | " + board[4][3] + " | " + board [4][4] + " | " + board [4][5] + " | " + board [4][6] + " | " + board [4][7]
print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
print "6: " + board[5][0] + " | " + board[5][1] + " | " + board[5][2] + " | " + board[5][3] + " | " + board [5][4] + " | " + board [5][5] + " | " + board [5][6] + " | " + board [5][7]
print

def make_user_move(board):

try:    
valid_move = False
while not valid_move:
    col = input("What col would you like to move to (1-7):")
    for row in range (6,0,-1):
        if (1 <= row <= 6) and (1 <= col <= 7) and (board[row-1][col-1] == " "):
            board[row-1][col-1] = 'X'
            valid_move = True
            break
    else:
        print "Sorry, invalid square. Please try again!\n"

except NameError:
print "Only numbers are allowed."

except IndexError:
print "You can only select columns from (1-7), and rows from (1-6)."

def make_computer_move(board):
```

# Code needed here...
   valid_move = False
   while not valid_move:
    row = random.randint(0,5)
    col = random.randint(0, 6)
    for row in range (5,0,-1):
        if board[row][col] == " ":
            board[row][col] = "O"
            valid_move = True
            break

```
def main():


free_cells = 42
users_turn = True
count = 1
ttt_board = [ [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " "," ", " ", " "],    [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [ " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "] ]

print "\nHALL OF FAME \n"

try:
hall_of_fame = open("HallOfFame.txt", 'r')

for name in hall_of_fame:
    print str(count) + ".", name
    print
    count += 1

hall_of_fame.close()

except IOError:
print "No Human Has Ever Beat Me.. mwah-ha-ha-ha!\n"

choice = raw_input("Would you like to go first? (y or n): ")

if (choice == 'y' or choice=='Y'):
users_turn = True


elif (choice == 'n' or choice =='N') :
users_turn = False        

else:
print 'invalid input'

while not winner(ttt_board) and (free_cells > 0):
display_board(ttt_board)
if users_turn:
    make_user_move(ttt_board)
    users_turn = not users_turn
else:
    make_computer_move(ttt_board)
    users_turn = not users_turn
free_cells -= 1

display_board(ttt_board)
if (winner(ttt_board) == 'X'):
print "You Won!"
print "Your name will now be added to the Hall of Fame!"

hall_of_fame = open("HallOfFame.txt", 'a')
name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
hall_of_fame.write(name+ '\n')
print "Your name has been added to the Hall of Fame!"

hall_of_fame.close()

print "\nGAME OVER"
elif (winner(ttt_board) == 'O'):
print "The Computer Won!"
print "\nGAME OVER"
else:
print "Stalemate!"
print "\nGAME OVER \n"

#start the game

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not indenting your for loops:

`for row in range(6):
    for col in range(3):
        if (board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] == board[row][col + 2] ==\
            board[row][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
        return board[row][col]`

The `:` denotes the need for an indent on the next line.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's a LOT more than just the for loops that are missing indentation :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a LOT of places where the indentation is just plain missing for inexplicable reasons. As @davidism mentions, indentation in python is used to indicate nesting levels; so this code is completely unusable in its current state.

Here's my attempt to GUESS what your code was MEANT to do, so you can get an idea of all the places where whitespace matters, but it is just missing in your code.

```
import random


def winner(board):
    for row in range(6):
        for col in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row][col + 1] == board[row][col + 2] == \
                        board[row][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]  # Check columns for winner

    for col in range(6):
        for row in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col] == board[row + 2][col] == \
                    board[row + 3][col]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]

# Check diagonal (top-left to bottom-right) for winner

    for row in range(3):
        for col in range(4):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row + 1][col + 1] == board[row + 2][col + 2] == \
                    board[row + 3][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]


# Check diagonal (bottom-left to top-right) for winner

    for row in range(5, 2, -1):
        for col in range(3):
            if (board[row][col] == board[row - 1][col + 1] == board[row - 2][col + 2] == \
                    board[row - 3][col + 3]) and (board[row][col] != " "):
                return board[row][col]

# No winner: return the empty string
    return ""


def display_board(board):


    print "   1   2   3   4    5   6   7"
    print "1: " + board[0][0] + " | " + board[0][1] + " | " + board[0][2] + " | " + board[0][3] + " |    " + board[0][
        4] + " | " + board[0][5] + " | " + board[0][6] + " | " + board[0][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---"
    print "2: " + board[1][0] + " | " + board[1][1] + " | " + board[1][2] + " | " + board[1][3] + " | " + board[1][
        4] + " | " + board[1][5] + " | " + board[1][6] + " | " + board[1][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
    print "3: " + board[2][0] + " | " + board[2][1] + " | " + board[2][2] + " | " + board[2][3] + " | " + board[2][
        4] + " | " + board[2][5] + " | " + board[2][6] + " | " + board[2][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
    print "4: " + board[3][0] + " | " + board[3][1] + " | " + board[3][2] + " | " + board[3][3] + " | " + board[3][
        4] + " | " + board[3][5] + " | " + board[3][6] + " | " + board[3][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
    print "5: " + board[4][0] + " | " + board[4][1] + " | " + board[4][2] + " | " + board[4][3] + " | " + board[4][
        4] + " | " + board[4][5] + " | " + board[4][6] + " | " + board[4][7]
    print "  ---+---+---+---+---+---+---+"
    print "6: " + board[5][0] + " | " + board[5][1] + " | " + board[5][2] + " | " + board[5][3] + " | " + board[5][
        4] + " | " + board[5][5] + " | " + board[5][6] + " | " + board[5][7]
    print


def make_user_move(board):    
    try:
        valid_move = False
        while not valid_move:
            col = input("What col would you like to move to (1-7):")
            for row in range(6, 0, -1):
                if (1 <= row <= 6) and (1 <= col <= 7) and (board[row - 1][col - 1] == " "):
                    board[row - 1][col - 1] = 'X'
                    valid_move = True
                    break
            else:
                print "Sorry, invalid square. Please try again!\n"
    except NameError:
        print "Only numbers are allowed."

    except IndexError:
        print "You can only select columns from (1-7), and rows from (1-6)."


def make_computer_move(board):
    # Code needed here...
    valid_move = False
    while not valid_move:
        row = random.randint(0, 5)
        col = random.randint(0, 6)
        for row in range(5, 0, -1):
            if board[row][col] == " ":
                board[row][col] = "O"
                valid_move = True
                break


def main():
    free_cells = 42
    users_turn = True
    count = 1
    ttt_board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                 [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]

    print "\nHALL OF FAME \n"

    try:
        hall_of_fame = open("HallOfFame.txt", 'r')

        for name in hall_of_fame:
            print str(count) + ".", name
            print
            count += 1

        hall_of_fame.close()

    except IOError:
        print "No Human Has Ever Beat Me.. mwah-ha-ha-ha!\n"

    choice = raw_input("Would you like to go first? (y or n): ")

    if (choice == 'y' or choice == 'Y'):
        users_turn = True


    elif (choice == 'n' or choice == 'N'):
        users_turn = False

    else:
        print 'invalid input'

    while not winner(ttt_board) and (free_cells > 0):
        display_board(ttt_board)
        if users_turn:
            make_user_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        else:
            make_computer_move(ttt_board)
            users_turn = not users_turn
        free_cells -= 1

    display_board(ttt_board)
    if (winner(ttt_board) == 'X'):
        print "You Won!"
        print "Your name will now be added to the Hall of Fame!"

        hall_of_fame = open("HallOfFame.txt", 'a')
        name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
        hall_of_fame.write(name + '\n')
        print "Your name has been added to the Hall of Fame!"

        hall_of_fame.close()

        print "\nGAME OVER"
    elif (winner(ttt_board) == 'O'):
        print "The Computer Won!"
        print "\nGAME OVER"
    else:
        print "Stalemate!"
        print "\nGAME OVER \n"

# start the game

main()
```